# Effective IPhone programming techniques

Tags: iphone

While creating an IPhone application I always care about techniques which greatly effect working of an application on one side *and* understanding of code on the other. For instance, I prefer creating **Singleton** to manage data, which separates *Data* from *View*. Similarly, use of **Asynchronous images** and **memory management** are few techniques which I always use whenever I work with some *web service* or any *database*.
What I believe is, there are a lot many *effective* programing techniques which programmers follow to make their application best presented before the client.
Which techniques I should  keep in perspective while creating an *IPhone* application which makes use of *web data* or *local data*? Are their concepts similar to *Singleton* which I should consider using in my application?

Thanks for letting out few of your secrets :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to add about the delegate pattern here. Its very helpful when you are waiting for async notifications.

Comment: Which all delegate methods are important?

Comment: Its a design pattern. So you can create objects of a particular class and implement its delegate. Now when a objects method is called it will process the info and call the delegate method. Its similar to table view delegate, parser delegate etc.

Answer (score 0):

A personal favourite of mine is to control and display gracefully any errors that occur in serving web data. For example if an application uses Async image loading (as you said) have a time out with an Image failed to load picture.

This presents a much nicer interface than a spinning wheel and lets the user know that its not working without them waiting for ages for something to happen.

If you want you can add a try again button to the image placeholder as well.

Comment: Ok. Can you suggest me other than Async images. I have used it couple of times in my application